# A simple Mean app not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to run a simple mean app and it is not working. i get the following error : http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/ng/areq?p0=meetupsController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined (Argument 'meetupsController' is not a function, got undefined)

Here is my code

server.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    app     = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/client/views/index.html');

});


app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/client/js'));
app.listen(3000, function() {
console.log('I mlistening on 3000');
})
```

my angular controller :

```
var app = angular.module('meetupApp', ['ngResource']);
app.controller('meetupsController', ['$scope', '$resource', function($scope, $resource){

    $scope.meetups = [
     {name : "First"},
     {name : "second"},
    ]

$scope.createMeetup = function(){
    $scope.meetups.push({name: $scope.meetupName});
    $scope.meetupName='';
}

}])
```

mu html file:

```
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div ng-controller="meetupsController">
        <h1>There are {{meetups.length}} meetups</h1>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="meetup in meetups">
            {{meetup.name}}
        </ul>
        <form ng-submit="createMeetup()">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Meetup name" ng-model="meetupName"></input>
            <button type="submit">Add</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/controllers/meetups-controller.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

please help

Comment: in your html file ng-app is not set to meetupApp

Comment: Also just fyi....its always easy to debug if minified source code is not used..

Answer (score 3):

In your `<html ng-app>` you should add your angular app like:

```
<html ng-app="meetupApp">
...
</html>
```